# How do I solve this differential equation from a previous exam?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This question was on a previous exam.

> "Assume that the concentration of a solution by time $t$ is given by $C(t)$, and assume that": 
>   $$
> \frac{dC}{dt} = 3(20 − C(t))
> $$
>
> a) solve for $ C(t)= 5$
>
> b) find $\lim_{t \to \infty} C(t)$
>
> c) use the answer in a) to find t when $C(t)= 10$

I started to separate dC/dt, so i got dC= (60- 3C(t)) * dt, and then I was a bit unsure about the rest, some integration must happen, but I am not sure of how to proceed.

Comment: Isn't some kind of initial value required? Also, how far did you get in this problem? If you don't provide your own thought and/or efforts, it's likely that this post will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: I started to separate dC/dt, so i got dC= (60- 3C(t)) * dt, and then I was a bit unsure about the rest, some integration must happen, but I am not sure of how to proceed..

Comment: Notice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Answer (score 1):

We have the first order linear differential equation

$$(1) \quad C'(t)=-3C(t)+60.$$

The general solution of the homogeneously equation

$$(2) \quad C'(t)=-3C(t)$$

is given by

$$ C_h(t)= \alpha e^{-3t},$$

where $ \alpha \in \mathbb R.$

It is easy to see that $C_s(t)=20$ is a special solution of $(1).$ Hence the general solution of $(1)$ is given by

$$ C(t)=20+ \alpha e^{-3t},$$

where $ \alpha \in \mathbb R.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: where did you get -60 from?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dC}{dt} = 3(20 − C(t))$$
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = -3( C(t)-20)$$
Is a first order differential equation that's also separable:
$$\frac{dC}{C(t)-20} = -3dt$$
Integrate:
$$\int \frac{dC}{C(t)-20} = -3\int dt$$
I let you finish.

Comment: That was very helpful!

Comment: you're welcome @norway96  .....